# Two specific files won't transfer to an external disk

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

The progress bar won't move, and the dialogue will just stay there hanging.  The files are small (<500 MB), so it's not an issue of the progress bar moving slowly because of the size.
The problem only happens with those two specific files (a couple of videos in .avi format); I've moved other files with the same format and about the same size both before and after attempting with said files, and they are moved as expected almost immediatly.
The names of the files don't include any weird characters, nor are they long enough to cause issues after taking the full destination path into account.

The moving action cannot be cancelled (since the cancelling window will just stay there hanging), and the only way to get rid of it is to unplug the external drive, then spend several minutes trying to launch the task manager (since it will slow down everything) and kill the dialogue -which kills explorer.exe in the process-, and then waiting some more minutes in order to restart explorer.exe and wait for the computer to start acting normally again.  Either that or doing a hard reset.

I've rebooted, tried to copy the files instead of moving them, ran a chkdsk on the external unit, used a different USB port, and of course, I've made sure that the files themselves aren't corrupted.

i7-2670QM, 2400 MHz with Win 7 Pro, SP1.
The external disk is a FAT32 (they gave it to me with a bunch of data which I have nowhere to put in order to change it to NTFS) with over a TB of free space.

I'm running out of ideas.  Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: I'm suspecting hardware issue with your internal hard disk(not the external one). It may have bad sectors so that part of the 2 files are not readable. you can try to copy these 2 files around within your internal hard disk and see if you encounter the same issue.

Comment: What parameters did you use with Chkdsk? chkdsk /F can be much more complete , without taking forever. Don't know why but if your trying to "fix" or see if it is broken, without that parameter it does not get the job done

Comment: Hm.  It would seem that the files actually have some sort of issue; I moved them to a different folder, and that worked, but then I got the issue when either trying to create a copy on the same drive or to compress the file in a .rar  Thanks for the replies.  I'll run  a chkdsk on the computer drive tomorrow, since I don't feel like spending the holidays troubleshooting the drive.  EDIT:  I ran it with /r, Psycogeek.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the integrity of the files by copying them to another folder on the same disk. If that operation succeeds, then try moving the copies to the external drive. If you cannot even copy them locally, and they're not in a protected location (e.g. a Windows subfolder), they may be damaged.

Another possibility is that the files contain characters that are problematic; I've encountered issues transmitting files with consecutive *null* characters, for example. **Try zipping the two files** and move the zip archive. Of course, getting the files off the USB drive in usable from will require un-archiving them, so it may not be a good work-around.